# So what really happens when we use 'new' in PHP

Tags: php, new-operator

So what really happens when someone say 'new' in PHP

I believe in C/Java, when new is called, memory is allocated for each instance variables that are needed for an object? (correct me if i am wrong)

Is this the same with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of PHP constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032808/purpose-of-php-constructors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `$var = new Class`

- a new object is created (memory allocated and initialized);
- its constructor, if any, is called;
- the object is put into a list of objects and given a unique id;
- a new *zval container*<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)</sup> is created, this container stores, inter alia, the id of the object;
- the variable `$var` is associated with this created *zval* container.

<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)</sup> [Definition of what's a *zval container*.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to check it for yourself using [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

```
echo memory_get_usage();
$obj1 = new obj1;
$obj2 = new obj2;
$obj3 = new obj3;
echo memory_get_usage();
```

Same is the case with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `new` in PHP, PHP assumes you'd like to call a `new Class`: [PHP Classes Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).