# Trouble with input error-checking system PHP

Tags: php, object

I'm trying to implement an error checking system with PHP (too few characters, blank input, etc...).

Right now, if I leave a blank title, the error is caught but it's not displaying the message. Here's the first part which actually checks the input ('ll just show for an event title)

```
Class check_errors{

function create_event_errors($event_title){
    global $submit_error;
    if($event_title == ""){
        $field = "event_title";
        $submit_error->setError($field,"Title cannot be blank");
    }
    elseif(strlen($event_title) < 5){
        $field = "event_title";
        $submit_error->setError($field,"Title must be longer than 5 characters");
    }
    elseif(strlen($event_title) > 75){
        $field = "title";
        $submit_error->generalError($field,"Title must be less than 40 characters");
    }
}
```

So, on the same page, here's the display_errors class

```
Class display_errors{
var $values = array();  //Holds submitted form field values
var $errors = array();  //Holds submitted form error messages

function setValue($field, $value){
     $this->values[$field] = $value;
  }

function setError($field, $errmsg){
    $this->errors[$field] = $errmsg; //if I echo this, the error message displays
    $this->num_errors = count($this->errors); //if I echo this, the # of errors displays
}

function value($field){
  if(array_key_exists($field,$this->values)){
     return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($this->values[$field]));
  }else{
     return "";
  }
}   

 function error($field){    
     if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors)){
        return $this->errors[$field];
     }else{
       return "";
     }
  }
}
```

**Now for the issue. When I try to check if errors are detected, it doesn't find anything**

```
$check_errors->create_event_errors($event_title); //submit the input to be checked

echo $display_errors->num_errors; //this does not display the # of errors. It does when I echo from within the function in the class though

if($display_errors->num_errors == 0){
   //submit event
}
```

Comment: The variables `$displa_errors` and `global $submit_error` are poiting to same object?

Comment: No, I just put that echo statement in there to see if I could access the errors and nothing appears. It's just for checking in that instance.

Comment: both objects should be the same

Comment: Which objects? I have one object to access the error_checking class, and another to access the display_errors class. They can't be the same.

Comment: You might want to avoid the use of the "global" keyword.  And look up the PHP function filter_var() because it can save you a good bit of work if you use it correctly.

Comment: `$display_errors` and `$submit_error` are 2 different instances of display_errors class? if so, that's why you cannot see the num_errors you store the data in one variable y try access it in another variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `var`, don't use `global` and define all properties. Also consider @harke's pointers for better code design.

```
class check_errors
{
    protected $errors;

    function __construct(display_errors $errors) {
        $this->errors = $errors;
    }

    function create_event_errors($event_title){
        if($event_title == ""){
            $field = "event_title";
            $this->errors->setError($field,"Title cannot be blank");
        }
        elseif(strlen($event_title) < 5){
            $field = "event_title";
            $this->errors->setError($field,"Title must be longer than 5 characters");
        }
        elseif(strlen($event_title) > 75){
            $field = "title";
            $this->errors->generalError($field,"Title must be less than 40 characters");
        }
    }
}

class display_errors
{
    protected $values = array();  //Holds submitted form field values
    protected $errors = array();  //Holds submitted form error messages
    public $num_errors = 0;

    function setValue($field, $value){
        $this->values[$field] = $value;
    }

    function setError($field, $errmsg){
        $this->errors[$field] = $errmsg; //if I echo this, the error message displays
        $this->num_errors = count($this->errors); //if I echo this, the # of errors displays
    }

    function value($field){
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->values)){
            return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($this->values[$field]));
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }   

    function error($field){    
        if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors)){
            return $this->errors[$field];
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Run the code

```
$display_errors = new display_errors();
$check_errors = new check_errors($display_errors);

$check_errors->create_event_errors($event_title); //submit the input to be checked

echo $display_errors->num_errors;

if($display_errors->num_errors == 0){
    //submit event
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a lot! Just curious, can you give a brief explanation on the construct? It almost appears as an inheritance-like functionality judging how you're using $this to call that function. I've seen them before, never used them though. I read this and it cleared it up a bit but I'd still like a little clarity in reference to your example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032808/purpose-of-php-constructors

Comment: $this means the current object. If you want to use the display_errors object in the check_errors object, you need to pass it. A common way to do this is through the constructor.

Comment: Note that it's calling $this->errors->setError(), which is the setError method of $this->errors, which is the display_errors object.

Comment: Sorry I was questioning the use of a constructor, I wasn't referring to $this. Thanks for clearing it up though!

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this causes you any trouble:

```
$field == "title";
```

This statement is as usefull as writing;

```
true or false;
```

You might have meant:

```
$field = "title";
```

(single equal sign)

---

Just to give you some pointers:

- Create validator classes (See: [*Interfaces <sup>Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/language.oop5.interfaces)).
- Create one class for the error collection.
- Create one class for a complex definition of validations and error messages.
- Allow to stack multiple of the last to be able to treat a collection of many validations as one (See: [*Composite Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)).

With that done you can validate and decide what to do with the outcome independently. Also it's easier to write the code, because you can not introduce so many errors and even if you do, those are easier to fix.

Also keep the concrete fieldnames independent to the validation.

Comment: I'll look further into this. Do you see any reason why my current setup isn't working? I can display the number of errors from within, but when I try to access that same variable from the outside it doesn't display anything.

Comment: No clue, your code looks pretty indirect, so I didn't look much closer. Maybe it's the use of equal signs (edited the answer, see what I put on top). Also you should really create yourself validator classes.