# What specifically is use of Constructors in PHP?

Tags: constructor

I need some explaination of what specifically is the benefit of constructors in PHP, I already know how constructors work but I am confused in understanding why and where are constructors used in PHP, any simple examples may help me understand well and will be highly appreciated, Thankyou!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032808/purpose-of-php-constructors

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a constructor is to make sure the object is 'ready' to be used.

```
<?php
class Person {
    function __construct($name, $gender) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }
}

$Fred = new Person('Fred', 'male');
?>
```

By using a constructor, you are able to specify the values the object *requires*, however optional properties can be left until later. In the above example it makes sure that every instance of `Person` has a name and a gender, allowing us to write methods that may require the name and/or gender without having to worry whether they have been initialised or not. The example isn't fool-proof, you could still pass in an empty string for either value, however inside the constructor you can put checks in to make sure that this doesn't happen or even limit the input to certain values. You could also make it so they default to certain values.

You should use constructors everytime you create a new object definition. Consider what values the object *must* have, and force them to be declared in the constructor.