# Class extending DateTime calls to parent constructor and gets NULL

Tags: php, datetime, extends

I'm trying to create a class that extends DateTime implementing a constructor that calls to parent's.
This always return NULL instead of an instance of the object. What's the reason for this behavior?

```
class TimeHandler extends DateTime{
        
       public function __construct(){
            $somevar = parent::__construct();
            echo gettype($somevar); //This always outputs NULL instead of object
        } 

}

$instanTH = new TimeHandler();
```

Comment: A constructor doesn't normally return a value, it works with the current object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of PHP constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032808/purpose-of-php-constructors)

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused about terminology NigelRen. I'm reading in PHP.net that PDO::__construct returns a PDO object on success (This makes that something similar to the code above works with PDO) while it states the following for DateTime::__construct: Returns a new DateTime instance.  I take for granted that a DateTime instance was the same as an object.

Comment: You can think of the `new` keyword returning the instance, not the constructor itself, it merely initializes state. You can call `new parent` to get an instance, but then `TimeHandler` won't be initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a constructor in the class extension if you don't want to do anything other than in the parent::__construct().

```
class TimeHandler extends DateTime{}       

$instanceTH = new TimeHandler('today UTC');

var_dump($instanceTH);
//object(TimeHandler)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-10-16 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

If the extension contains a constructor then a parent :: __ construct with all necessary parameters must also be executed in this one so that the extended object is correctly initialized.

```
class TimeHandler extends DateTime{
  
  public function __construct($dt = null, $timeZone = null){

    parent::__construct($dt, $timeZone);

  }
  
}
```

An example of a DateTime extension can be found [here](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt).